# Using CD74HC4067 16-Channel Analog Multiplexer Demultiplexer is not working as expected

Tags: arduino-nano, multiplexer, keypad

I am working on a project that needs multiple digital signals and I am considering the CD74HC4067 (on a break-board) to work as a multiplexer. More specifically i am trying to build a keypad with multiple ttp123 break-boards. Each ttp123 signal is connected to one of the 0-15 pins of the CD74HC4067. The S0-S3 pins are connected to digital Pins D6 to D9 on a pro mini. Signal is on A0 and EN is on A1. A1 and EN have a 4K7 resistor to ground. I power the setup with a separate 5v and the arduino is connected on a pc usb port.

I expect when a ttp123 is pressed to trigger a HIGH and this event to be passed to SIG pin. Here is my code:

```
//Using CD74HC4067 16-Channel Analog Multiplexer
//Mux control pins

int s0 = 6;
int s1 = 7;
int s2 = 8;
int s3 = 9;


//Mux in "SIG" pin
int SIG_pin = A0;
int EN_pin  = A1;

void setup(){
  pinMode(s0, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(EN_pin, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(s0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EN_pin, LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("keypad interfacing_CD74HC4067 starting...");
}


void loop(){
  String a;
  //digitalWrite(EN_pin, HIGH);
  Serial.println(" press any key to continue ...");
  //digitalWrite(EN_pin, LOW);
  while (!Serial.available());
  while(Serial.available()) {
    
  //Loop through and read all 16 values
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
    //Serial.print("Value at channel ");
    //Serial.print(i);
    //Serial.print("is : ");
    //Serial.println(readMux(i));
    
      float volts = readMux(i);
          
      Serial.print("Value at channel ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(" is : ");
      Serial.print(volts);
      Serial.println();
    
    //delay(1000);
  }
  a= Serial.readString();// read the incoming data as string
}
}
float readMux(int channel){
  int controlPin[] = {s0, s1, s2, s3};

  int muxChannel[16][4]={
    {0,0,0,0}, //channel 0
    {1,0,0,0}, //channel 1
    {0,1,0,0}, //channel 2
    {1,1,0,0}, //channel 3
    {0,0,1,0}, //channel 4
    {1,0,1,0}, //channel 5
    {0,1,1,0}, //channel 6
    {1,1,1,0}, //channel 7
    {0,0,0,1}, //channel 8
    {1,0,0,1}, //channel 9
    {0,1,0,1}, //channel 10
    {1,1,0,1}, //channel 11
    {0,0,1,1}, //channel 12
    {1,0,1,1}, //channel 13
    {0,1,1,1}, //channel 14
    {1,1,1,1}  //channel 15
  };

  //loop through the 4 sig
  
  for(int j = 0; j < 4; j ++){
    digitalWrite(controlPin[j], muxChannel[channel][j]);
  }
  //read the value at the SIG pin
  int val = analogRead(SIG_pin);

  //return the value
  float voltage = (val * 5) / 1024.0;
  return voltage;
}
```

Just for simplicity, I have connected only one ttp123 on the system, ttp123 signal to channel12 on 74HC4067. With ttp123 touched, I would expect to get a high on SIG when I write {0,0,1,1}, to S0-S3. All other channels should be LOW. However here is what I get:

On my first run after a boot:

```
press any key to continue ...
Value at channel 0 is : 2.53
Value at channel 1 is : 2.58
Value at channel 2 is : 2.53
Value at channel 3 is : 2.60
Value at channel 4 is : 2.51
Value at channel 5 is : 2.55
Value at channel 6 is : 2.50
Value at channel 7 is : 2.52
Value at channel 8 is : 2.42
Value at channel 9 is : 2.47
Value at channel 10 is : 2.43
Value at channel 11 is : 2.50
Value at channel 12 is : 2.40
Value at channel 13 is : 2.43
Value at channel 14 is : 2.38
Value at channel 15 is : 2.44
```

and then after each sample run all channels seem to get lower values...

```
press any key to continue ...
Value at channel 0 is : 1.70
Value at channel 1 is : 1.76
Value at channel 2 is : 1.71
Value at channel 3 is : 1.78
Value at channel 4 is : 1.70
Value at channel 5 is : 1.76
Value at channel 6 is : 1.72
Value at channel 7 is : 1.77
Value at channel 8 is : 1.67
Value at channel 9 is : 1.72
Value at channel 10 is : 1.69
Value at channel 11 is : 1.76
Value at channel 12 is : 1.69
Value at channel 13 is : 1.73
Value at channel 14 is : 1.67
Value at channel 15 is : 1.74
```

and I get no HIGH on channel 12 as I should.

Is there a need for a pullup or pulldown resistors in this setup? Should I connect a resistor to each S0-S3 with ground? Why is this not working?

Edit: [image: schematic]

When the system is resting I measure 4.93V at the ttp's Vs to GND and 0V TTP_SIGNAL to GND. When ttp's are touched TTP_SIGNAL to GND i measure a 3.94-3.88v. But the strange thing is that when i touch the ttp's I measure 2.xx Volts at all the mux channels. I think that there must be some kind of short circuit somewhere but it is not visible. The problem is that I can't test another CD74HC4067 since i  have only one right now. Unless there is another suggestion I will look for a couple of these (CD74HC4067)  as soon as possible.

Edit2:

I got hold of a new CD74HC4067 and connected just one capacitive touch pad. When nothing is touched/pressed, i get the following:

```
press any key to continue ...
Value at channel 0 is : 1.01
Value at channel 1 is : 0.90
Value at channel 2 is : 0.81
Value at channel 3 is : 0.62
Value at channel 4 is : 0.44
Value at channel 5 is : 0.42
Value at channel 6 is : 0.43
Value at channel 7 is : 0.43
Value at channel 8 is : 0.31
Value at channel 9 is : 0.28
Value at channel 10 is : 0.24
Value at channel 11 is : 0.18
Value at channel 12 is : 0.15
Value at channel 13 is : 0.23
Value at channel 14 is : 0.22
Value at channel 15 is : 0.13
```

When i touch the pad (connected to c0) i get:

```
press any key to continue ...
Value at channel 0 is : 4.15
Value at channel 1 is : 3.74
Value at channel 2 is : 3.75
Value at channel 3 is : 3.54
Value at channel 4 is : 3.76
Value at channel 5 is : 3.33
Value at channel 6 is : 2.88
Value at channel 7 is : 2.64
Value at channel 8 is : 3.77
Value at channel 9 is : 3.52
Value at channel 10 is : 3.07
Value at channel 11 is : 2.76
Value at channel 12 is : 2.04
Value at channel 13 is : 1.83
Value at channel 14 is : 1.67
Value at channel 15 is : 1.51
```

I measure volts between signal and ground at the capacitive touch pad, when touched i get 3.9v

Comment: You've mentioned separate supply, begginers loves to forgot ground connections. Anyway slowly changing adc readings somewhere far from 0 or 5 usually indicates floating input. You have to measure everything, test that mux separately...

Comment: @KIV thank you for your comment. The grounds of the two separate sources are connected. I will measure everything again and will come back.

Comment: Posting a schematic of how you have it wired will help a lot. Even a hand drawn schematic is better than a frizzy picture.

Comment: @Gil i edited the question as you suggested.

Comment: I got a new CD74HC4067 and tested it. I edited the post above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to get a solution to my problem. There was a cabling and a software issue as well. Firstly, I pulled down the Signal with a 10K resistor. In this way I stopped having those random volt measurements.
[image]

Secondly, in the code, I had an elementary failure to initialize the A0 analog pin as:
pinMode(SIG_pin, INPUT);

Here is the final code:

```
// interfacing mux with tp223

//Mux control pins

const int s0 = 6;
const int s1 = 7;
const int s2 = 8;
const int s3 = 9;

//Mux in "SIG" pin
int SIG_pin = A0;
int EN_pin  = 10;

void setup(){
  pinMode(s0, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(SIG_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(EN_pin, OUTPUT);
  
  digitalWrite(s0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EN_pin, LOW);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("keypad interfacing_CD74HC4067 starting...");
}

void loop(){
    
  //Loop through and read all 16 values
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
      int val = readMux(i);
      
      if (val > 0) {
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print(" pressed ");
        Serial.print(val);
        Serial.println();
      }
  }
  
}
float readMux(int channel){
  int controlPin[] = {s0, s1, s2, s3};

  int muxChannel[16][4]={
    {0,0,0,0}, //channel 0
    {1,0,0,0}, //channel 1
    {0,1,0,0}, //channel 2
    {1,1,0,0}, //channel 3
    {0,0,1,0}, //channel 4
    {1,0,1,0}, //channel 5
    {0,1,1,0}, //channel 6
    {1,1,1,0}, //channel 7
    {0,0,0,1}, //channel 8
    {1,0,0,1}, //channel 9
    {0,1,0,1}, //channel 10
    {1,1,0,1}, //channel 11
    {0,0,1,1}, //channel 12
    {1,0,1,1}, //channel 13
    {0,1,1,1}, //channel 14
    {1,1,1,1}  //channel 15
  };

  //loop through the 4 sig
  for(int j = 0; j < 4; j ++){
    digitalWrite(controlPin[j], muxChannel[channel][j]);
  }
  //read the value at the SIG pin
  int val = digitalRead(SIG_pin);
  //return the value
  return val;
}
```